# Get content-length of file with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know there is a server variable `%{HTTP:Content-Length}` for working around content-length, but as it's not well documented or maybe I didn't find, I don't know if it goes for client sent-bytes or content length of requested URL.

But I want to get content-length of requested URL (in my case they are files). Is there any variable for it?

Answer (score 0):

The variable `%{HTTP:Content-Length}` gives the content-length header field of the http request.

A very nice .htaccess documentation can be found here:

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess.html

Comment: So isn't it possible to get content length of URL itself?

Comment: I guess no, but you can easily do it using a php script - if you have a php engine running.